# Possible to use "while" in NodeJS routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just encountered a strange behavior. I've a MongoDB collection `allCustomers` and trying to fill it up, as long as the `Customers.countDocuments()` returns a value lower than 3. Model and Schema are exported and properly accessible, since it's adding the entry by using `if`, instead of `while`. Unfortunately that's not my requirement and I it's not reasonable to me.

```
let Customer = require('./models/customer');

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Customer.countDocuments({}, function (err, count) {
        while (count < 3) {
            var emptySlot = new Customer({ name: 'Unused', gender: 'empty' });
            emptySlot.save(function (err, slot) {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                console.log(slot.name);
            });
          }
        });
        Customer.find({}, function (err, customers) {
            ..
    });
});
```

Comment: You forgot to increase `count` after savinging new document.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc that wouldn't work yet

Comment: `emptySlot.save()` is async so need to wait for it to finish before run `Customer.find()`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc the while loop is synchronous, it won't reach the `Customer.find`.

Comment: The `count` variable needs to be increased in **synchronous** task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Where do you initialise the variable `count`?
2. Where do you increase the variable `count`, in order to stop the loop?
3. Do you know how [asynchronous javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) works?

The while loop is a synchronous task, and it will be kept executing until it reaches the end (JavaScript **is not** multi-threaded). Every asynchronous task that get instanced, will be temporary saved in a *event-loop* chain and they will be executed, in order, when the synchronous task is completed.

In your case, even if you increase the variable `count` inside the `save` callback, the loop will still be infinity. The `save` callback won't be ever called, since the synchronous task never ends.

The result is that you call `save` infinity times and you never go out.

A better solution can be implemented using `Promise.all`

Comment: Okay, I got that. I'm not sure how to apply your advise on using `Promise.all`.